# unexpected output with string slicing when tested with multiple inputs

Tags: python-3.x

the assignment asks, "Assign sub_lyric by slicing rhyme_lyric from start_index to end_index which are given as inputs."

Sample output with inputs: 4 7

```
start_index = int(input())
end_index = int(input())
rhyme_lyric = 'The cow jumped over the moon.'
sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[::1]
print(sub_lyric)
```

when it tests with inputs 4 and 7 I get the expected "cow" but when the program tests with inputs 8 and 14, it still gets "cow" but expects "jumped" when using the [start:end:step]. How do I achieve both expected outputs?

Comment: `sub_lyric = rhyme_lyric[start_index:end_index:1]`

Comment: intriguing. Mad I didn't think of that.

Comment: Worked? I'll add it as an answer